# Firebase query is nil with queryStarting(atValue: self.startKey)

Tags: firebase

I am trying to implement a pagination in my app.

This is my structure in Firebase:

[image]

This is my Firebase query:

```
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "postDate")
        ref.queryStarting(atValue: self.startKey).queryLimited(toFirst: 4).observeSingleEvent(of: .value)
```

Where "self.startKey" = -Lw3xFbQO2PzZU5x2zxv

When I remove the queryStarting, the query works.

At which point is my Firebase query wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've correctly identified, your issue is caused by `queryStarting(atValue: self.startKey)`.

The `atValue` parameter of `queryStarting` refers to the value that your query is ordered by. By default, because queries are ordered by key, `queryStarting` would work as you expect. However because you have used `queryOrdered(byChild: "postDate")`, `atValue` is now the starting value of `postDate` not the key. To paginate the data as you would expect, you would need to use the `postDate` value of `-Lw3xFbQO2PzZU5x2zxv`, not the key name.

```
queryStarting(atValue: self.startDate) // where self.startDate is the value of /path/to/${self.startKey}/postDate
```

However, there may also be a case where two separate keys share the same post date. To handle this case, use the two parameter form of [`queryStarting`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseQuery#querystartingatvalue:childkey:) and pass in both the value of `postDate` and it's corresponding key:

```
queryStarting(atValue: self.startDate, childkey: self.startKey) // where startDate is the value of /path/to/${self.startKey}/postDate
```

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you and I understand your answer. But it does not matter which data I give the function in childKey. I could write "blablabla", and it has no effect. The query will always return me the last 4 or the first 4 of all 13 items, depending on queryLimited. Any ideas? I am trying to setup an collectionView, where the oldest items are on the bottom. Thank you so much

Comment: I've reworked the answer to clarify what `queryStarting` does when used with `queryOrdered`. I had to go back and refresh my knowledge to see my mistake.